# how to transform object list with list attribute to one list with all list attribute itemes contained

Tags: java, guava

I have an object like:

```
class House {

    String name;

    List<Door> doors;

}
```

what I want to do is to tranform a `List<House>` to a `List<Door>` containing all `doors` of all `houses`.

Is there a chance to do this with guava?

I tried with guava used Lists.transform function but i only getting a `List<List<Door>>` as result.

Answer (score 9):

If you really need to use a functional approach, you can do this using [FluentIterable#transformAndConcat](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transformAndConcat-com.google.common.base.Function-):

```
public static ImmutableList<Door> foo(List<House> houses) {
    return FluentIterable
            .from(houses)
            .transformAndConcat(GetDoorsFunction.INSTANCE)
            .toImmutableList();
}

private enum GetDoorsFunction implements Function<House, List<Door>> {
    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public List<Door> apply(House input) {
        return input.getDoors();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
FluentIterable.from(listOfHouses).transformAndConcat(doorFunction)
```

would do the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Guava for it (assuming I understood you correctly):

```
final List<Door> doorsFromAllHouses = Lists.newArrayList();
for (final House house : houses) {
  doorsFromAllHouses.addAll(house.doors);
}
// and doorsFromAllHouses is full of all kinds of doors from various houses
```

Using `Lists.transform` for input `list of houses` and transform function `get all doors from a house` gave you correct output of `list of *each house's doors*` (which is exactly `List<List<Door>>`).

More generally you want [`reduce` / `fold` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduce_%28higher-order_function%29) instead of transform, which isn't implemented in Guava ([see this issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=218)), mostly because Java's verbose syntax and presense of for-each loop which is good enough. You'll be able to reduce in Java 8 (or you are able to do this in any other mainstream language nowadays...). Pseudo-Java8-code:

```
List<Door> doors = reduce(
  houses,                                  // collection to reduce from
  new ArrayList<Door>(),                   // initial accumulator value
  house, acc -> acc.addAll(house.doors));  // reducing function
```